# Load different video in HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have an HTML5 video tag that I dynamically load. Here's my HTML:

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
    <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here is my JavaScript for loading the video:

```
function RunVideo(index) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvPresentations");
    var cell = grid.rows[(+index) + 1].cells[2].innerHTML;
    var player = document.getElementById('video');
    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('source');
    var movie = cell;

    player.pause();

    mp4Vid.setAttribute('src', movie);

    player.load();
    player.play();
}
```

The first time I load a video (from a grid view) it works fine. But any subsequent ones I try to load I get the following message in the video player:

`Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path.`

How can I correctly unload the current video in order to reload a new one?

---

### Edit

- It seems to be an IE only bug. It does work in other browsers like a charm.
- It is able to play each video individually on load (i.e if no other `src` have been set before).
- The links and code are ok then.
- It throws a `MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.` error.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

After I tested with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0w1o6yL/1/), the bug doesn't raise, so my assumptions were incorrect.
Which leaves you with the only choice of trying to re-encode your videos.

---

**Original answer:**

It seems you are facing an IE bug, when setting the source element with different `codecs`(not type).
I think that the browser automatically assigns for himself the [`codec`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4281) parameter, in the [type attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-type) and doesn't update it when the new src is set.

Even if all your videos are encapsulated in `.mp4`, the codecs may vary.

You can find a list of codecs that IE does support [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Graphics/VideoFormatSupport/Default.html). Basically, `.webm`, '
H.264 high profile' and `H.264 baseline profile`.

One possible workaround you may try, if my assumptions are correct, is to create a new `source`element each time you call your `RunVideo` function.

```
function RunVideo(index) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvPresentations");
    var cell = grid.rows[(+index) + 1].cells[2].innerHTML;
    var player = document.getElementById('video');
    var oldMp4Vid = document.getElementById('source');
    var movie = cell;
    var newmp4Vid = document.createElement('source') 
    newMp4Vid.src = cell;
    player.removeChild(oldMp4Vid);
    player.appendChild(newMp4Vid);
    player.load();
    }
```

I'm not sure it will do the trick and I'm not sure what the specs tells about setting `<source>` new src on the flow like that, but if this problem is only present in IE, it's probably a bug from them, maybe you could [fill a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback).

Alternatively, you could re-encode your videos with the exact same codec.

Comment: Thanks for trying but that didn't work. :( Pretty sure it's not the format of the videos because they all play on IE. This only happens if I play one and then try and play another. I am beyond frustrated.

Comment: @user3715441 yeah that's what I said in the edit, "my assumptions were incorrect". That is really a strange bug, which am unable to reproduce. If you can try you code with differrent video files, maybe you'll be able to find what is going on.